# JSP Include based off of URL Query

Tags: jsp, if-statement, dynamic, include, conditional-statements

I have a page with a url of:

> domain.com/page.jsp?pID=01

And I have code:

```
<% String pID; %> <% if (request.getParameter("pID") == "01") { %>
     <%@include file="page01.jsp" %>
             <% } else if (request.getParameter("pID") == "02"){ %>
     <%@include file="page02.jsp" %>
             <% } %>
```

All I get is a blank page.  Why is this?

Comment: I meant `request.getParameter("pID") == "02"`

Comment: by swapping out request.getParameter("pID") == "02" with request.getParameter("pID").equals("02") solved the issue.  Thank you.

Comment: also see JSTL, scriptlets are old old day programming

Comment: I'm just using this for an example, not for the finished web solution